# Testing the bloc state will pass even if some properties are not the same

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, bloc

This is `mapEventToState` of `MyBloc`:

```
@override
  Stream<MyBlocState> mapEventToState(MyBlocEvent event) async* {
    if (event is MyBlocInitialize) {
      yield MyBlocStateInitialized(event.something);
    }
```

where the states are defined like:

```
abstract class MyBlocState extends Equatable {
  EnterCredentialsState([List props = const []]) : super(props)
}

class MyBlocStateInitialized extends MyBlocState {
  final String _something;
  MyBlocStateInitialized(this._something);}
```

and the event like:

```
abstract class MyBlocEvent {}

class MyBlocEventInizialize extends MyBlocEvent{
  final string something;
  MyBlocEventInitialize(this.something);
}
```

Now, this is my test:

```
test('Should return MyBlocInitialized with a defined String', () {
    String _somethingString = 'Something';

expectLater(
_myBloc.state,emitsInOrder([
          MyBlocsStateUninitialized(),
          MyBlocStateInitialized(_somethingString)
        ]));

    _myBloc.dispatch(MyBlocEventInitialize(_somethingString);
}
```

The problem with this test is that it will just check if the bloc will yield `MyBlocsStateUninitialized` and `MyBlocStateInitialized`, but it will not check the string inside `MyBlocStateInitialized`. Actually I could also change in

```
expectLater(
_myBloc.state,emitsInOrder([
          MyBlocsStateUninitialized(),
          MyBlocInitialized('WRONG')
        ]));

    _myBloc.dispatch(MyBlocEventInitialize(_somethingString);
}
```

and it would still pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you have a comparable param on your state you have to pass it to the parent constructor - `Equatable` - as you did with `MyBlocState`, otherwise it will be initialized with an empty list and you will receive a false positive when compared.

From Equatable

> The constructor takes an optional [List] of `props` (properties) which will be used to determine whether two [Equatables] are equal.
>   If no properties are provided, `props` will be initialized to an empty [List].

```dart
abstract class MyBlocState extends Equatable {
  EnterCredentialsState([List props = const []]) : super(props)
}

class MyBlocStateInitialized extends MyBlocState {
  MyBlocStateInitialized(this._something): super([_something]);
  final String _something;
}
```